# how to convert windows service written with python to exe

Tags: windows, python-3.x, service

This code hase to run in python python test.py install and python test.py start
and I convert to exe with pyinstaller doesnt work.

I wanna one file for customer.
how to run with format exe without using python test.py install?

```
class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "my_service_name"
    _svc_display_name_ = "my service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(lambda x: True, True)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self.run = False

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.run = True
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        while self.run == True
            try :
                <your code>
            except :
                time.sleep(3)
                <may be an error log here>



if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```